# Adding time to an existing file in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to update an existing file.txt in Python, which has two columns, one for days, and one for time, so that it will sum up a new time in another column on the same file.

```
Sunday      07:00
Monday      07:35
Tuesday     05:35
Wednesday   06:45
Thursday    08:40
```

For example, adding 30 minutes:

```
Sunday      07:00   07:30
Monday      07:35   08:05
Tuesday     05:35   06:05
Wednesday   06:45   07:15
Thursday    08:40   09:10
```

Comment: what does this have to do with the django tag? :)

Comment: Could you add some code you have already tried?

Answer (score 2):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module is very helpful for this. It lets you create [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) objects and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects which can be added together by simply using the `+` operator. So, to add thirty minutes to 08:30:25:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> d = datetime.strptime("08:30:25", "%I:%M:%S") + timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> d.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
'09:00:25'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [139]: d='Sunday      07:00'

In [140]: b=d.split()

In [141]: b
Out[141]: ['Sunday', '07:00']

In [142]: (datetime.datetime.strptime(b[1], '%H:%M') + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime('%H:%M')
Out[142]: '07:30'
```

Comment: outfile=open('file.txt','w')<br>
<br>
dict={}<br>
<br>
for line  in file('file.txt','r'):<br>
       (key, val) = line.split() <br>
       dict[key] = val <br>
print dict<br>
<br>
<br>
obj=Salestracker()<br>
for i in dict.keys():<br>
      outfile.write(i)<br>
      val =dict.get(i)<br>
      outfile.write(' ')<br>
      outfile.write(val)<br>
      outfile.write(' ')<br>
      for i in range(1,5):  <br>  
        q=int(raw_input("enter the sale after each 1 hr"))<br>
        val=obj.updateSales(val,q)<br>
        outfile.write(val)<br>
        outfile.write(' ')<br>
   outfile.write('\n')

Comment: @Cottoncandy Edit your original question to include that code. Its unreadable as the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

f=open("testcase","r") #open the file

pairs = [l.split() for l in f.readlines()] #get [day,time] pairs

f.close()

#this long line creates a list of [day,time1,time2] using list comprehensions
#you can change it a bit to change the output format.
data = ["%s%s%s\n" % (p[0].ljust(12),p[1].ljust(8), 
    (datetime.strptime(p[1],"%H:%M") + timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%H:%M")) 
    for p in pairs]

#reopen the file for writing and store the new data.
f = open("testcase","w")
f.writelines(data)
f.close();
```